# "Permission denied" if a file doesn't eixist

Tags: bash, scripting

I run this in bash:

```
sudo ./my_script.sh arg1 >& result.log
```

And I'm getting this:

```
-bash: result.log: Permission denied
```

if result.log doesn't exist. However, I don't want it to exist before I run a script and want it to be created. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the correct permissions to write a new file in the directory where result.log should be created. If it's already been created, you likely have permissions on that specific file to be able to write to it.

Change the permissions on that directory so that you are able to write in the directory.

Comment: why? it's sudo and I'm able to crate a new file

Comment: This post explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr

Essentially, when you use sudo, any output redirection is performed as your own user, not as root.